# readHTMLTable() can't work well for grabing a special form in a url

Tags: r, xml, web-crawler, rcurl

Question: I use readHTMLTable() in package(XML) to grab a form in a website("http://www.gaokao.com/e/20201106/5fa4f625338d0.shtml "). But the form is special and looks like the writer merges some cells. So when I grab it, the result is wierd as you can see in the pitcure. So What shoud I do? I heard that there are a lot of masters in the community. So I come here. Thanks a lot!!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MTqp.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nN4X.png)

Here is my code:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)
myHttpheader <- c(
  "User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.48 Safari/537.36 QQBrowser/7.7.31732.400",
  "Accept"="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
  "Accept-Language"="en-us",  "Connection"="keep-alive",
  "Accept-Charset"="GB2312,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
  "Referer"="http://t.dianping.com/")
url = "http://www.gaokao.com/e/20201106/5fa4f625338d0.shtml"
temp<-getURL(url,httpheader = myHttpheader,.encoding = "GB2312")
temp1<-iconv(temp,"GB2312","UTF-8")
doc<-htmlParse(temp1,asText = TRUE,encoding = "UTF-8")
table1<-readHTMLTable(doc,header = TRUE,which = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by using package'rvest'.

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)
url = "http://www.gaokao.com/e/20201106/5fa4f625338d0.shtml"
temp<-read_html(url,encoding = "gb2312")
node<-html_node(temp,"table")
html_table(node,header = TRUE)
```

But there is still a question remained that whether python is better than R in web-crawler?